# Android - Button must clicked twice to work

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

i've an activity with a bar with some buttons and a webview under.
To every button is associated an url, to i perform an `onClickListener` to load the url associated in the webview.

My problem is that buttons must be clicked twice before webview load url.

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".005"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
        >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/db1"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:text="VETRINA"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:textColor="@color/silver"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/db2"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:text="ANNUNCI"
                android:textColor="@color/silver"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/db3"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:text="NOTIZIE"
                android:textColor="@color/silver"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/db4"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:text="UTILI"
                android:textColor="@color/silver"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/db5"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

                android:background="@drawable/round_corner"
                android:text="YOUTUBE"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:textColor="@color/silver"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/db6"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:text="ANNUNCI"
                android:textColor="@color/silver"
                android:textSize="20dp" 
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.pack.MyWebView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".995" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the `onClickListener`

```
private void initButton(){
    bottoni = new Button[6];
    bottoni[0] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.db1);
    bottoni[1] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.db2);
    bottoni[2] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.db3);
    bottoni[3] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.db4);
    bottoni[4] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.db5);
    bottoni[5] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.db6);
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
        setListB(bottoni[i],buttons[i]);
    }
}

private void setListB(Button b,String content_b){
    String[] all = content_b.split("@@");
    final String title = all[0];
    final String link = all[1];
    b.setText(title);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            web.loadUrl(link);
        }
    });
}
```

How can i fix it? Thanks!!!

Comment: Where do you do `initButton()` ?

Comment: at the end of 'onCreate' of activity

Comment: it's not the answer for your question but for performance reasons you shouldn't be creating several new OnClickListeners, you can have only 1 listener and use switch(v.getId()) to compare which button was clicked and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the method name(May be it will confuse the compiler) and use switch when using many buttons. Not sure about the method name, just give it a try.

Answer (score -1):

Create a `clickedButton` variable at the class level

`View clickedButton;`

and the `onClick` goes as follows (I am assuming `onClick` is common for all buttons).

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (clickedButton == null) {
        clickedButton = v;
    } else {
        if (clickedButton == v) {

            // load url and set clicked button to null
            loadUrl();
            clickedButton = null;
        } else {
            clickedButton = v;
        }
    }

}
```

Good luck :)

Comment: onClick is not common for all buttons.. as you can see i loop trought all buttons setting onclick for each one

Comment: scuse me.. but your login is the opposite of my question.. in your way i MUST click twice to loadUrl.. i need to click one time to load..

Comment: I think even though the `onClick` is not common it should work, since clicked button will be used as a common variable between all the buttons ;)

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly you want? What I understood is you need to open a `URL` in a `WebView` by clicking a button twice.

Comment: add all the buttons into another view like ListView.then listview will get the first click and the inner buttons will get the next (second) click.so ultimately your webview will load the url on second click.

Comment: no.. actually to load url associated to a button i have to click it twice ( i don't know why.. i see on web and someone talks about the first click is to take focus and second to click, but i've added to layout android:focusableInTouchMode="false" and it continue to give me what i don't want). My question is how to fix it.. so i need to click only one time on button to load url not twice.. :) sorry but i know that my english is not very good :)

Comment: Where on the web you find this `i see on web and someone talks about the first click is to take focus and second to click`? can you please refer some link. and why you did this `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` ?